# KendoUI Chart not consuming JSON dataSource

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, data-visualization

I have a Kendo UI Chart:

```
function createkpiBreakdownChart(labelPosition) {
    $("#kpiBreakdownChart").kendoChart({
        theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "metro",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '../Test/GetData',
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "customerSatisfactionChart"
        },
        series: [{
            field: "KPITestColumnValue"
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "KPITestColumnName"
        },
        title: {
            text: "Customer Satisfaction"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom",
            visible: false,
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: "#ffffff"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar"
        },
        //series: [{
        //    name: "Performance Metrics",
        //    data: [4.552162849872774, 4.391752577319588, 4.215633423180593, 4.345108695652174, 4.4728682170542635, 4.387005649717514, 4.351351351351352]
        //},],
        valueAxis: {
            minorUnit: .25,
            majorUnit: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            plotBands: [{
                from: 4,
                to: 5,
                color: '#000000',
                opacity: .1
            }],
            labels: {
                labels: {
                    format: "N0"
                },

            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "N0"
            }
        },
        //categoryAxis: {
        //    categories: ['Ease of requesting help', 'Time to reach qualified technician', 'Time to provide a solution', 'Completeness of solution', 'Technical ability & product knowledge', 'How well we kept you informed', 'Overall opinion of service'],
        //},
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "#.##"
        }
    });
}
```

That is rendering blank. When I run an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../Test/GetData',
}).done(function (data) {
    var customerSatisfactionChartData = data;
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
})
```

in Firefox using Firebug I receive this JSON back:

```
{"customerSatisfactionChart":[{"KPIColumnName":"Time To Reach Qualified Tech","KPIColumnValue":3.579831},{"KPIColumnName":"Completeness Of Solution","KPIColumnValue":3.359243},{"KPIColumnName":"Opinion Of Overall Service","KPIColumnValue":3.720588},{"KPIColumnName":"Tech Ability And Prod Knowledge","KPIColumnValue":3.636554},{"KPIColumnName":"Time To Provide Solution","KPIColumnValue":3.285714},{"KPIColumnName":"Ease Of Requesting Help","KPIColumnValue":3.758403},{"KPIColumnName":"How Well Are You Kept Informed","KPIColumnValue":3.262605}]}
```

I'm trying to figure out why the Kendo chart is not consuming this correctly? This is in the response field in my console but I'm guessing I don't currently have it in a format that Kendo will consume? If that is the issue is there a way to correct it via parse or parameter map potentially? Thanks.

Comment: maybe calling `createkpiBreakdownChart` function inside `done` would work?

Comment: Thanks, I had not tried that yet, but it still didn't work.

Comment: 1) is there any error in your console?

Comment: Have you used e.g. Fiddler to see if the chart is trying to load anything? You should see a request for ../Test/GetData occurring soon after the page loads. If not, you probably have the dataSource set up wrong. If yes, then the error should be somewhere in the rest of your chart setup.

Comment: I'll check with fiddler thanks for the tip. There is not an error in the console.

Comment: Fiddler returns: 
200 HTTP localhost:51093 /Test/GetData 546 private   application/json; charset=utf-8

However when I got to JSON it has a structure that is a little different than console, maybe that is just fiddler but it is:

    JSON
       customerSatisfactionChart
        {}
            KPIColumnName="Foo"
            KPIColumnValue=FooValue

And it repeats that structure for all 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '../Test/GetData',
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "customerSatisfactionChart"
    },
```

`schema` is part of the `DataSource`, so should be:

```
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '../Test/GetData',
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
        schema: {
            data: "customerSatisfactionChart"
        },
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it and now the data is loading correctly. I really appreciate it. (Btw side note please keep the blog going I've found it useful getting into Telerik/Kendo). Thanks again.